# replace normal number with tel:number

Tags: javascript, replace

I am reading an article on https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/369751/iphone-telephone-numbers-active-link-to-call#post1593120

I do not understand what is the meaning of `$1`. Could you please help me?

Secondly, I am working on this code

```
$('li').each(function() {
  $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/(\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d)/g,'<a href="tel:$1">$1</a>') );
});
```

Could you please help me on replacing a string of 10 numbers with a link to make a phone call.

Comment: Does what you have work, or not, and if not, how?

Comment: The format typically used is `<a href="tel:123456789">Call Us</a>`

Comment: The meaning of `$1` is [what the documentation says it is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

Comment: @John, you have replaced the original question (http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41605337/6) with a completely different question altogether which makes the comments and answers completely irrelevant. You should avoid doing this and ask a new question in such cases. If you want you can delete this question but please don't replace it.

Comment: If you have a new question, please use the "Ask Question" link at the top of the page instead of editing your current questions.

Answer (score 0):

About

> I do not understand what is the meaning of $1

Here is what you need to check: [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_parenthesized_substring_matches)

> Could you please help me on replacing a string of 10 numbers with a link to make a phone call.

The code that you have got works perfectly fine.

```js
$('li').each(function() {
  $(this).html( $(this).html().
      replace(/(\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d)/g,'<a href="tel:$1">$1</a>') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul>
  <li>123-456-7890</li>
  <li>Call us: 123-456-7890</li>
</ul>
```

Or for testing about `$1`, `$2` and so on:

```js
$('li').each(function() {
  $(this).html( $(this).html().
      replace(/(\d\d\d)-(\d\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)/g,
              '<a href="tel:$1$2$3">$1-$2-$3</a>') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul>
  <li>123-456-7890</li>
  <li>Call us: 123-456-7890</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a regular expression, everything within the `(...)` is "captured" in a capture group. (catchy title) These are remembered in the order they appear, 1, 2 etc...

To access those groups later in functions that work with regexes, you would use their numerical reference with a `$`.

So here `/(\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d)/` captures the phone number into capture group `$1` which is referenced in the replacement string, bada bing bada boom, phone number placed into the href and innerHTML. Sets up the search and replace in one fell swoop.

reference:
[regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)